# Subquery returned more than 1 value. Who can help me solve the problem?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, subquery

The query below is producing the error message `subquery returned more than one value`.

How should I change the query to avoid this error?

Query:

```
SELECT
STK.SPECODE AS 'Space Code',
STK.STGRPCODE AS 'Group Code',
STK.LOWLEVELCODES1 AS 'index',
ISNULL(STK.CODE,0) AS 'Item Code',
ISNULL(STK.NAME,0) AS 'Item Name',
ISNULL(BRC.BARCODE,0) AS 'Barcode',
ISNULL(STK.VAT,0) AS 'Vat',
ISNULL(STK.SELLVAT,0) AS 'Sell Vat',
ISNULL((select top 1 FYT.PRICE from LG_114_PRCLIST FYT where FYT.CARDREF=STK.LOGICALREF AND FYT.PTYPE=1 ),0) AS [Purchase Price (Excluding VAT) ],
ISNULL((select top 1 FYT.PRICE from LG_114_PRCLIST FYT where FYT.CARDREF=STK.LOGICALREF AND FYT.PTYPE=2 AND FYT.PRIORITY=2  ),0) AS [Sale Price (including VAT)],
(SELECT
   SUM(TOT.ONHAND)
FROM
   LV_114_01_STINVTOT TOT, LG_114_ITEMS STK
WHERE
   TOT.STOCKREF=STK.LOGICALREF AND TOT.INVENNO=-1 
   GROUP BY STK.CODE,STK.NAME     
   ) AS MIKTAR 
FROM LG_114_PRCLIST AS FYT LEFT OUTER JOIN LG_114_ITEMS AS STK ON STK.LOGICALREF=FYT.CARDREF 
LEFT OUTER JOIN LG_114_UNITBARCODE BRC ON BRC.ITEMREF=STK.LOGICALREF 
LEFT OUTER JOIN LV_114_01_STLINE HAR ON HAR.STOCKREF=STK.LOGICALREF 
Where BRC.BARCODE<>'' AND STK.ACTIVE=1
GROUP BY
FYT.CARDREF,STK.SPECODE,STK.STGRPCODE,STK.LOWLEVELCODES1,STK.CODE,STK.NAME,BRC.BARCODE,STK.VAT,STK.SELLVAT,STK.LOGICALREF
```

Thanks!

Comment: The subquery which you have aliased as `MIKTAR` is probably the cause of the problem here.  It would almost certainly return more than one record, assuming there is more than one group in your data.  I can't give an exact answer, because I don't know your data.

Comment: [edited] made question explicit

Answer (score 1):

I see that inside subquery OP joined `LV_114_01_STINVTOT` with `LG_114_ITEMS`. I guess it could be done just by simple `LEFT JOIN` and `SUM`:

```
SELECT
    STK.SPECODE AS 'Space Code',
    STK.STGRPCODE AS 'Group Code',
    STK.LOWLEVELCODES1 AS 'index',
    ISNULL(STK.CODE,0) AS 'Item Code',
    ISNULL(STK.NAME,0) AS 'Item Name',
    ISNULL(BRC.BARCODE,0) AS 'Barcode',
    ISNULL(STK.VAT,0) AS 'Vat',
    ISNULL(STK.SELLVAT,0) AS 'Sell Vat',
    ISNULL((select top 1 FYT.PRICE from LG_114_PRCLIST FYT where FYT.CARDREF=STK.LOGICALREF AND FYT.PTYPE=1 ),0) AS [Purchase Price (Excluding VAT) ],
    ISNULL((select top 1 FYT.PRICE from LG_114_PRCLIST FYT where FYT.CARDREF=STK.LOGICALREF AND FYT.PTYPE=2 AND FYT.PRIORITY=2  ),0) AS [Sale Price (including VAT)],
    SUM(TOT.ONHAND) AS MIKTAR               -- THIS
FROM
    LG_114_PRCLIST AS FYT
LEFT OUTER JOIN
    LG_114_ITEMS AS STK ON STK.LOGICALREF = FYT.CARDREF 
LEFT OUTER JOIN
    LG_114_UNITBARCODE BRC ON BRC.ITEMREF = STK.LOGICALREF 
LEFT OUTER JOIN
    LV_114_01_STLINE HAR ON HAR.STOCKREF = STK.LOGICALREF
LEFT JOIN                                   -- THIS
    LV_114_01_STINVTOT TOT                  -- THIS
        ON TOT.STOCKREF = STK.LOGICALREF    -- THIS
        AND TOT.INVENNO = -1                -- THIS
WHERE
    BRC.BARCODE <> ''
    AND STK.ACTIVE = 1
GROUP BY
    FYT.CARDREF,
    STK.SPECODE, STK.STGRPCODE,
    STK.LOWLEVELCODES1,
    STK.CODE, STK.NAME,
    BRC.BARCODE,
    STK.VAT, STK.SELLVAT, STK.LOGICALREF
```

Answer (score 0):

Move your subquery to FROM section as CROSS (or OUTER) APPLY

```
SELECT ...
   t1.MIKTAR
FROM ...
CROSS APPLY(
   SELECT SUM(TOT.ONHAND) AS MIKTAR
   FROM LV_114_01_STINVTOT TOT, LG_114_ITEMS STK
   WHERE TOT.STOCKREF=STK.LOGICALREF AND TOT.INVENNO=-1 
   GROUP BY STK.CODE,STK.NAME     
   ) t1
```